# Django to javascript template tag

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

How do you convert a paragraph of text to something that can be assigned to a javascript variable with django template tags?

eg.

```
var myVar = {{ my_bio }}
```

where my_bio is some long paragraph of text with new lines, and other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `escapejs` template tag was created for this purpose, you can [have a look at the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs) for use cases and examples.

Example:

```
>>> from django.utils.html import escapejs
>>> escapejs('a\nb')
u'a\\u000Ab'
```

You can, of course, [check out the code itself](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L62)!

Comment: Will escapejs escape new lines also?